# Remove an intermediate GIT commit

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I have an intermediate git commit which i have merged into the code now. It happened by mistake. I have 2 options:

1. Delete the project from gerrit, for which i have to install the delete-project plug in
2. Delete the commit from the GIT repository.

I would like to have suggestions on using the second option as i do not have the admin access to install the plugin.

commit 1

commit 2

I would like to keep the commit 1 and delete the commit 2.  The commit 2 is a direcotry which has many number of files in it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you've already pushed, the only safe thing you can do is a `git revert`. Altering published history is not worth the headache.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of either:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722046/remove-intermediate-commit-in-visual-studio-online
or:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113322/remove-4-commits-from-my-git-history

Another thing is not clear with the question: what exactly does "merged into the code" mean? Pushed to a remote? Merged into another branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 4 commits from my git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113322/remove-4-commits-from-my-git-history)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the latest commit(s), git rebase is probably your best bet: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 0):

What about a normal revert? You want to purge it because of its size?

Then you need the `Force Push` access right [EDIT: in Gerrit], which enables you to do a

```
git push --force
```

after you skipped back that one commit with

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Be aware that rewriting history is to be avoided when working on a  repository with a team of developers.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are looking for

`$ git reset --hard REF`

Here `REF` will be `SHA1` of `commit 1` .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want to get rid of one commit.

If you haven't already pushed out the commit, you could drop it locally with

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

which checks out the revision right before the current.
Your history before: `commit1--commit2`
Your history after:  `commit1`

If you already pushed the commit, as long as there's no critical in `commit2` (huge, passwords, etc), it's better to keep `commit2` in the history and revert the commit instead of dropping it:

```
git revert <sha-of-commit2>
```

This will create a NEW commit that reverts the changes made by `commit2`.
Your history before: `commit1--commit2`
Your history after: `commit1--commit2--commit3`

Comment: I have already pushed the commit.. and just got the confirmation that i can delete both of these commits..so now i have 2 delete the first 2 commits.