# Remove intermediate commit in Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-rewrite-history, tfvc

I edited my README.md multiple times because I didn't see the preview button. Now my commit history is full of useless commits.

Can I remove some of them, or at least hide them ?

Comment: I honestly hope not.  Being able to modify history sounds like a pretty bad feature for a source control system to have.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it isn't possible, since I chose git for the underlying version control system.

Comment: Git or otherwise, I would hope that wouldn't be supported in *any* source control system.  Being able to change history kind of defeats the purpose of a tool that tracks history.

Comment: Sure, but I'm a neat freak. Anyway thanks for your insight.

Comment: @David it's actually a handy feature, particularly for a Distributed System.

Comment: @Abizern: Being able to change history wouldn't be a feature, it would be a bug.  The whole point of source control is to permanently track incremental changes to the source.  There isn't much use to an audit log which can be modified after the fact.

Comment: While I agree that rewriting history can scare the hell out of people, it's a well supported feature of both TFVC and git. Though Git allows much more extensive history rewrites than TFVC.

Comment: @David, rewriting in Git is discouraged for *shared* commits, but there is no problem whatsoever with locally rewriting your own private commits before publishing them. This is incredibly freeing, as it lets developers commit as frequently as they wish, then clean things up (exactly as the OP wants to do) before pushing tidy commits to the rest of the team. Note that, at least with Git, "rewriting history" is a bit of a misnomer. In reality, you create *new* commits reflecting a different history and share those instead of the originals.

Comment: I will have to look into that rebase option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### CAUTION

**History rewriting can get your source control system in a pretty messed up state. Make sure you have a good backup of your sources in case anything goes wrong.**

### Git

Depending on your Team Project setup, the Readme.md is stored in a Git repository you can absolutely rewrite history and force push the squashed commits back to TFS, essentially making it forget the in-between data. This is done using `git rebase` and cannot be done through the Visual Studio Online site nor through the Visual Studio Tools for Git. You will need to do it from the commandline.

The whole process is [explained very well in the Git-SCM wiki](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). You'll need to do the following steps:

1. From an account with [Force Push permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#Git) clone your repository containing the readme.md.
2. use `git rebase -i HEAD~6` (6 being the number of commits to rewind)
3. use `Squash` to [merge the commits together](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits)
4. use `git push --force origin master` to force the history rewrite on the remote

**Note**: this will change the hash of the commit and every commit that came after. After doing this, either warn all other contributors to resync or be sure that no others have worked on the repo after you made these commits.

### TFVC

If your Team Project is configured using TFVC, then the process is slightly different.

1. Make sure you have a copy of the file you want to keep.
2. Destroy the file in source control using `tf destroy $/Teamproject/readme.md`, If need be you can use the `/keephistory /stopat:C12345` option to destroy the data in specific change sets at the end of a file's history.
3. Now copy your backed-up file back into place
4. and check it in as you'd usually do or from the commandline `tf add $/teamproject/reqadme.md` followed by `tf checkin`. If you kept history around, TFVC will reconnect it. If you completely destroyed the history, TFVC will just add a new file.