# How to remove a file from Visual Studio Online and its history

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We are very new to using Visual Studio Online.  After some discussion we have decided to not keep our web.config files in the cloud.  It was easy enough to remove it from the project, however, the file still exists in the changesets and history.  Is there a way to wipe it from the cloud either through the website or visual studio?  We are using 2015.  Thanks.

**EDIT** We are using Team Foundation Version Control.

Answer (score 1):

[Destroy Command (Team Foundation Version Control).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx)

You need to destroy the file you want and then you will have to commit to save the changes. With this the file and it's entire history will be deleted. See if this helps.

Comment: I saw that when I was looking for an answer and that would be great if we used TFS, but we are using the cloud.  How do you execute commands to the cloud?

Comment: You use "Visual Studio Command Prompt" to execute this command & then commit your changes to the cloud. The VSO will automatically change the history for using Destroy Command.  [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722046/remove-intermediate-commit-in-visual-studio-online), Check this out.