# Is it possible to see if a forced push was done on a git enabled tfs repository?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

Is it possible to see if a forced push was done on a git enabled tfs repository?

In the tfs UI under "history" there are two options, "commits" and "branch updates". Under "branch updates" I think you see all pushes that have been done to the repository. In one of those I can see that a number of commits has been deleted, and the deleted commits is not visible in the tab where you see the commit history. Does this mean that this push was forced or is it any other way to delete commits (already pushed to the repository) without reverting them and make a new commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is now available in newer TFS versions. I do not know since which version this feature is available but with Azure DevOps (TFS) you can do the following:

[image]

Under `Repos` --> `Pushes` you see all Pushes for your selected Branch. If push was executed with `force` than the push is marked with the label `Force push`

Answer (score 1):

No there is no this option and "tag" to see this. And also there is **not any other way to delete commits without reverting them and make a new commit.** If you can see a number of commits has been deleted which just means the history has been rewrite and force pushed.

In TFS,rewrite or destroy history are also using rebase,squash command and need (force push) permissions for a branch. Detail steps is explained very well in the [Git-SCM wiki](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). You'll need to do the following steps:

1. From an account with [Force Push permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#Git) clone your
   repository.
2. use git `rebase -i HEAD~6` (6 being the number of commits to rewind)
3. use `Squash` to [merge the commits together](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits)
4. use `git push --force origin master` to force the history rewrite on
   the remote

More details please  refer this link from MSDN: [Apply changes with rebase](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/rebase) and this similar question [Remove intermediate commit in Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722046/remove-intermediate-commit-in-visual-studio-online)

Comment: So no way to detect it with git reflog on the TFS server side then?

Comment: @VonC there is a table called `tbl_GitRefLog`  in TFS datebase. However can't see the related info in web portal,

Comment: This answer is outdated, with newer versions of TFS you can see all pushes and the have a label if they are forced pushes.